# python FancyURLopener timeout

Tags: python, timeout, urllib

is there a way to set connection timeout for FancyURLopener()?
I'm using FancyURLopener.retrieve() to download a file, but sometimes it just stucks and that's all... I think this is because it's still trying to connect and it's not possible. So is there a way to set that timeout?

Thanks for every reply

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `retrieve()` with a timeout, you can set it in the `socket` module.

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/urllib2.html#sockets-and-layers

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, solved.
I didn't realize that I could use something like this...

```
fileName = string.split(url, '/')[-1]
data = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout = 5)              //Connection timeout set to 5 secs
newF = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fileName), "wb")
newF.write(data.read())
newF.close()
```